# OSGI Felix with Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, osgi, glassfish-4, apache-felix, equinox

I want to create a Module to generate reports using OSGI (Felix in Glassfish),

First, I have downloaded and deployed the Jasper Reports Bundle, The Deploy returns "OK"

After, I have created a Project Bundle that imports the Jasper Reports Packages, the Deploy of Bundle returns "OK"

I take the OutputStream of the Servlet and I Take the Jasper InputStream from another Bundle, and process this with this Code.

```
public void generateReportFromDatasource(InputStream inputStream,
                                         OutputStream outputStream,
 Map parameters,
 JRDataSource jrDataSource) {

    try {
        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(inputStream, outputStream,
                parameters,jrDataSource);

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

But, the Jasper Report result is a Error, But i cannot read cleary.

```
[2014-10-23T17:22:36.362-0300] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=24     _ThreadName=Thread-4] [timeMillis: 1414095756362] [levelValue: 1000] [[
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:124)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:104)
   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:62)
   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:108)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:668)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:649)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:437)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:858)
at com.roshka.javorai.report.client.JavoraiReportManagerimpl.generateReportFromDatasource(JavoraiReportManagerimpl.java:75)
```

My question is, I don't cant see the Error, because the JasperReports Bundle have the JRStyledTextParser and I cant see the Class that it says that not has  Found.

Comment: The test unit, (without OSGI) works OK

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have all required packages imported. 
The Manifest of your servlet containing bundle needs to import it like the following:

```
Package-Import: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util
```

Comment: I have the Import, I solve my problem with this https://github.com/ieugen/jasperreports-5.1.2-osgi

Comment: well, yes you also need a bundle exporting those packages :-)